# How to remove the item from the local storage by clicking on div?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am having two bootstrap cards. On selecting one card the card details are going to the array in the local storage. Now I want is if I click another card the previous card details should be removed and the new card details should get into the array.

```
$("#room_next").click(function (){

    localStorage.setItem("object", JSON.stringify(object));

}) 

var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
```

Here #roomnext is the next button id and object is the array name as of now the two card details are storing in the array of local storage. I need only one which is selected.

Comment: Use localStorage.removeItem('object'); first then use setItem to set the object of new card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Use : `localStorage.removeItem('object');` to remove object saved as `object`.

`window.localStorage` Supports mainly 5 methods:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'): 
/* Add key and value to localStorage  */
```

```
localStorage.getItem('key')  // returns 'val' 
/* Retrieve a value by the key from localStorage */
```

```
localStorage.removeItem('key')
/* Remove an item by key from localStorage */
```

```
localStorage.clear()
/* Clear all localStorage */
```

```
localStorage.key(index)  //retrun key
/* Passed a number to retrieve nth key of a localStorage */
```

Comment: i think you can give a `<div data-local-id="some_id">...</div>`  to each div. you can store this `id` into local localstorage accross a specific key (let it be `selected_key`). then you can simply use `setItem` to replace the same. @G.Lakshmi  I hope this will work. You donot have to use removeItem for this unless you weant to unset the same.

Comment: So I think you want to save the card even after restarting the browser no?

Comment: ```var main_2 = $('#main_2'), main_3 =  $('#main_3');  ```

```function refresh_set(el){
    $(".blue").removeClass("blue"); 
    $(el).addClass("blue");
    localStorage.setItem('selected_id', $(el).attr('id')): 
}```

```
$('#main_2').click(refresh_set); 
$('#main_3').click(refresh_set);
```

Comment: you mean to save card ids in a variable and call a function right? after that where should I keep by button function my requirement is after clicking card it should go to array and after clicking button it should finalize.

Comment: if so. It will be better to store that id in a global variable;  after confirmation,(on button click), you can write it to local storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203639/discussion-between-jerrychayan-and-g-lakshmi).

Answer (score 0):

As the Mozilla Docs,

We have the method `removeItem()` from the `Storage` API.

You can check the API [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage);

There is another one, `clear()` to remove everything.

I recommend to you to check typescript, and so you will be able to have autocomplete in your development evironment.

Comment: @ Mathias  you right only but i need the previous clicked card data to be removed and present clicked card data to be added at the same time into local storage

Answer (score 0):

If you can Identify the object that you want to delete by ex : object_Id or something. Then you can pass the object to the `localStorage.removeItem('key');`in order to delete the object you want.

For example :

```
function populateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
  localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');
  localStorage.setItem('image', 'myCat.png');

  localStorage.removeItem('image');
}
```

you can set the object like this you can remove what you want like this. In this example the image is deleted.
you can refer [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) to learn more.

The parameter you are passing to the removeItem() should be a String specifying the name of the item you want to remove.

Comment: I had given like localstorage.removeitem('object') and I am getting error as Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.removeitem is not a function
Please help me out

Comment: use `removeItem` ; ( ' `I` ' is capital)  @G.Lakshmi